# Auto refresh in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

In the following code, on autorefresh the timer starts when all the queries are sent, but I want the timer to start when all the ajax queries are completed.
How can I go about it?

```
    $scope.autoRefresh = function(){
    $scope.running = !$scope.running;
    $scope.timeoutsec = 10;
    if($scope.running)
    {
        $scope.timer = setInterval($scope.refresh, 10000);
        $scope.count = $timeout($scope.countdown,1000);
    }
    else
    {
        clearInterval($scope.timer); 
        $timeout.cancel($scope.count);
    }
}
```

countdown function --

```
    $scope.countdown = function(){

    $scope.timeoutsec = $scope.timeoutsec - 1;
    $scope.count = $timeout($scope.countdown, 1000);

}
```

refresh function --

```
    $scope.refresh = function(){
    // update function
    $scope.timeoutsec = 11;

}
```

Edit:
update function --

```
    $scope.update() =function(){
        for(var i=0;i<cluster.length;i++)
        {
         var request = $.ajax(cluster[i]).success(function(data, status, headers, config)              
            {
                 // on success
            });
        }
        }
```

Comment: What ajax queries? Please show all of the relevant code.

Comment: You don't show your queries here, but if it's `$http` or `$resource` requests we are talking about (returning promises, that is), this sounds like the perfect case for `$q.all([promise1,promise2,promise3]).then(callback);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xmlhttp request, you have to set third parameter in xhr.open() function as true. This will make the request synchronous, shown below :

```
 xhr.open(method, url, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some boilerplate code for you to see how it could be done.

```
(function() { 
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')

        .controller('controller', function($scope, $http, $timeout, $q) {
            $scope.update = function () {

                // single request
                $http.get('url')
                    .then(function (data) {
                        $timeout($scope.update, 10000);
                    });

                // or with multiple requests
                var request1 = $http.get(/****/);
                var request2 = $http.get(/****/);
                var request3 = $http.get(/****/);

                $q.all([request1, request2, request3])
                    .then(function() {
                        $timeout($scope.update, 10000);
                    });
            }; 
        });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialise $scope.running to be false, only on the press of auto refresh button running should be set to true.

```
    $scope.running = false;
```

autorefresh function -

```
    $scope.autoRefresh = function(){
    $scope.running = !$scope.running;
    $scope.timeoutsec = 10;
    if($scope.running)
    {
        $scope.count = $timeout($scope.countdown,1000);
    }
    else
    {
        $timeout.cancel($scope.count);
    }
}
```

countdown function --

```
    $scope.countdown = function(){
    $scope.timeoutsec = $scope.timeoutsec - 1;
    if($scope.timeoutsec == 0)
    {
        $scope.refresh();
    }
    whenAll($scope.queries).done(function(){
    $scope.count = $timeout($scope.countdown, 1000);
});
```

refresh function ---

```
    $scope.refresh = function(){
    div.style.visibility = "visible";
    $scope.update();
    $scope.timeoutsec = 11;
}
```

whenall function --

```
    function whenAll(promises) {
    var i, data = [],
    dfd = $.Deferred();
    for (i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {
        promises[i].done(function(newData) {
            data.push(newData);
            if (data.length == promises.length) {
                dfd.resolve(data);
            }
        }).fail(function() {
            data.push("NO DATA");
            if (data.length == promises.length) {
                dfd.resolve(data);
            }
        });
    }
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Push all your ajax queries to $scope.queries.

Answer (score 0):

Push all your $http ajax into an array, like so, since $http return promises, youcan  use the $q API to handle when all requests are finished:

```
var httpPromises = [
    $http({method:'GET', url: '/myjson0.json'}),
    $http({method:'GET', url: '/myjson1.json'}),
    $http({method:'GET', url: '/myjson2.json'}),
    $http({method:'GET', url: '/myjson3.json'})
];


//handle your requests like you would normally do
httpPromises[0].success(...).fail(...);
httpPromises[1].success(...).fail(...);
httpPromises[2].success(...).fail(...);
httpPromises[3].success(...).fail(...);

// remember to inject $q in your controller/factory
$q.all(httpPromises,function(){
    //start your timer here
});
```

[$q documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)